# Add two JSON roots to JSON in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I am using below code to generate JSON, but I cannot seem to find a way to add an extra "root" to the JSON.
I have tried to add multiple "roots" by using subqueries, but it does not work as it puts the "connection" root under the other.

```
SELECT 
       [cola] as [source.name]
      ,[colb] as [destination.name] 
FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('connection')
```

It returns below JSON:

```
{
  "connection": [
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "val1"
      },
      "destination": {
        "name": "val2"
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "val3"
      },
      "destionation": {
        "name": "val"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to return:

```
{
  "type": "iwantthistobeincluded",
  "connection": [
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "val1"
      },
      "destination": {
        "name": "val2"
      }
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "name": "val3"
      },
      "destination": {
        "name": "val4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in another select?

```sql
select "iwantthistobeincluded" AS type
, (
SELECT 
       [cola] as [source.name]
      ,[colb] as [destination.name] 
FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
FOR JSON PATH
) as connection
for json path
```

Comment: The solution does not work as it puts connection "under" the "iwantthistobeincluded"

Comment: that's what i get for not testing. how about this version

Comment: A little hint too, if would behoove you to add some test data to your question so it's easy to setup a working example :)

Comment: Almost worked, just needed WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER to remove square brackets, but I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add tag type in First Tage

```
SELECT 
       [cola] as [source.name]
      ,[colb] as [destination.name] 
FROM #Test
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('type: iwantthistobeincluded,connection')
```

You can insert Example Data   with the following codes

```
create table #Test(cola varchar(100),colb varchar(100))
insert into #Test
(cola,colb)
select 'val1','val2'
union select 'val3','val4'
```

Comment: This solution almost works, but i litterally want "type": "iwantthistobeincluded",
  "connection": - with double quotes